# PHP replace double backslashes "\\" to a single backslash "\"

Tags: php, string, replace, backslash

Okay so im working on this php image upload system  but for some reason internet explorer turns my basepath into the same path, but with double backslashes instead of one; ie:

```
C:\\Documents and Settings\\kasper\\Bureaublad\\24.jpg
```

This needs to become C:\Documents and Settings\kasper\Bureaublad\24.jpg.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`stripslashes`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php) function.

That should make them all single slashes.

Comment: stripslashes did not work for me. Both backslashes were remove from the tmp_name path, so I keep looking...

Comment: Why would this convert \\ to \?  I need this, but when I use stripslashes() it...strips all of the slashes.

Answer (score 2):

Note that you may be running into PHP's Magic Quotes "feature" where incoming backslashes are turned to `\\`.

See
https://www.php.net/magic_quotes

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered the stripslashes() function?

http://www.php.net/stripslashes